# Multiple page number positions in one document

Tags: numbering, positioning, fancyhdr

I'm working on a document with multiple page number styles. The introduction consists of Roman (I, II, III,...) page numbers, the actual text consists of page numbers in Arabic style (1, 2, 3,...), and the appendices pages are numbered with a hyphenated letter-number (A-1, A-2, A-3,..).

This is all going well, but here comes the problem.

The second appendix (B-1, B-2, B-3,...) consists of drawings (imported PDF files on full scale of an A4 page format). The page number and the drawing are overlapping. [image: ()].

The page number is marked by the green rectangle and black rectangles consist of personal information that is blacked out.

Is it possible to move the page numbering (only for this appendix) to one of the positions marked with a red rectangle?

I'm using the fancyhdr package in a report document class (given by my boss).

Shout if you need some more information and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You could use the `\newgeometry` feature of the `geometry` package to change page margins on the fly.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're setting the content yourself (through regular text, say) or including full-page PDFs from an external source (using [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), say), I'd suggest setting a new page style where the page numbers are lowered into position.

Here's an example showing how it can be done if you're setting the text yourself (while I'm using `article`, it holds for other base classes as well):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{appendixA}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{A-\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{appendixB}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{B-\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy % Just for this example

\pagestyle{appendixA}
\section*{Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{appendixB}
\section*{Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

I define a specific page style for the differing footer-positioned page numbers, lowering them into position using `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}` (with `<len>` negative). `[0pt][0pt]` ensures that the resulting box doesn't have any height or depth and therefore won't impede on the baseline height (if that's an issue).

If you were including full-page PDFs via `pdfpages`, this is what things might look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{appendixA}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{A-\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{appendixB}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{B-\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy % Just for this example

\pagestyle{appendixA}
\section*{Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{appendixB}
\section*{Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-3] % Some introductory text
\includepdf[
  pagecommand = {\thispagestyle{appendixB}}
]{example-image-letter-numbered}% From //ctan.org/pkg/mwe

\end{document}
```

You have to set the page style specifically using `\thispagestyle{<your page style}` (using the `pagecommand` key-value) since the default is to use an `empty` page style with `\includepdf`.

Similar approaches can also be followed using [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic), if needed.

Comment: I assume that the "similar approaches" involve placing the page number at absolute page position (perhaps using `textpos`)? That's what I would do.

Comment: @RobtAll: Yes. [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) provides a similar technique for placing content in absolute positions on the page, and that content could be a external image (or page from a PDF) together with textual content. It's done before page shipout, so page numbering would be correct.